# Automated DataSet/DataTable instead of SQLCommands

Tags: .net, database, vb.net

I used to do all the database logic with SqlCommand and the Methodes ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonReader and never used something like DataSet or Datatable.

```
Dim dbcon As Data.Common.DbConnection
Dim cmdselect = dbcon.CreateCommand()
cmdselect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1"
cmdselect.ExecuteReader()

Dim cmdupdate = dbcon.CreateCommand()
cmdselect.CommandText = "UPDATE FROM useres WHERE id = 1 SET name = 'newname'"
cmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is sometimes hard to administrate. So I would like to use a more efficent way. May thought was to Query a DataTable, make changes to it and then call .AcceptChanges and all changes where wrote back to the Database. But this seems not to be the way it works?
The method .Update requires that i bring with my own update command, if i have to do that myself, why using the datatable, dataset... anyway?

How do you write your DB Backend?

- With SQLCommands arrays and variables?
- With DataSet, DataTable?
- With a VisualStudio genereated template?
- With Linq?

I really don't know which way to go....

Answer (score 0):

First of all read some articles describing Database/Entity Providers documentation.
You have to know that a good DB provider uses Datatables + Linq for database "actions" and another abstraction layer for entity manipulation (with bidirectional Datatable <-> Entities conversion through custom operators).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will depend substantially on where the data is coming from and where it needs to go, both now and in the future.

If web services or WCF services are being used or will be used, then DataTable/DataSet is not an appropriate solution since these entities either don't serialize or don't serialize well in these scenarios.

My personal preference, even though it is a bit more work up front, is to create classes for all data entities (sometimes known as data transfer objects or DTOs) and create database code that works with these entities.

I know that there are object/relational mapping (ORM) components available that will reduce the burden on you, but we found it just as easy to write our own database mapping code that allows us to easily move objects in and out of the database using reflection.

Here are the two main practices that I recommend since they have allowed us to scale our applications to tens of thousands of users and support multiple clients (ipad, android, winforms, silverlight, web clients) with the exact same database backend and DTOs:

As much as possible, embed your database interaction in stored procedures. This makes it much easier to fix and change behavior than trying to track down SQL scattered throughout your code. It also reduces the potential for SQL injection attacks and improves database performance.

Create classes that map directly to the database tables. You can use automation tools such as CodeSmith Generator to create classes and CRUD stored procedures from your database tables. This practice allows you to perform automatic mapping from the database tables to your DTOs and from your DTOs to your stored procedure parameters using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Serpen,

I used to write entire applications the way you describe it. I do know it can be a pain sometimes, for example when working with hundreds of querys in hundreds of tables.

My advice to you is to switch to the **ADO.NET Entity framework / Linq**. It has a very low learning curve, it should not take you more than a day to do the most CRUD operations.

I found myself saving up to 80% of my time, no longer needing to write all those querys.

Alternative, you can use for example Telerik OpenAccess ORM Free edition to try it out.
They have a very good documented quickstart witch should you get started in a couple of hours.